# HTMLTextWriter to render elements in the middle of the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, htmltextwriter

Using asp .net and C# I've managed to use a HTMLTextWriter in my override Render method to render two divs. But they appear at the end of the page, how can I choose where to render these divs if I needed them to appear in a particular asp panel for example?

Thanks a lot,

Dan

EDIT: My bit of code:

```
    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        base.Render(writer);
        using (HtmlTextWriter writer2 = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter))
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, "testDiv");
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Div);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you´ll need to use a HTML parser like [Majestic](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php). You can render your page into a memorystream and then manipulate it as you want.

If the only problem is to customize the panel rendering, you can write a control that inherits `asp:panel` and inserts the desired classes.

Comment: Are you sure that's the only solution? I want to do exactly what I'm doing now - but just place the code on a different part of the page!? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you have 2 options, create a control that inherits panel and add that behavior, or, modify the page rendering result.